# Why $Nx = Ny \Rightarrow xy^{-1} \in N \textrm{ if } N \lhd G?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose we have the quotient group $\frac{G}{N}$ and $x,y \in G$. If $Nx \in \frac{G}{N}$ and $Ny \in \frac{G}{N}$, prove that $Nx = Ny \Rightarrow xy^{-1} \in N$.

Comment: I think you $\LaTeX$ed too hard. ;)

Comment: @SpamIAm sorry im noob:)

Comment: Anyway, what have you tried?  Note that $x = 1x \in Nx = Ny$.

Comment: If $z = nx = n'y$, then $nxy^{-1} = n'$. You can continue from here right?

Comment: The claim does not even require that the subgroup $N$ is normal!

Comment: Recall the equivalence relation that defines the set $G/N $. It is not necessary that $N $ be normal.

Comment: @Nameless thanks. solved:)

Answer (score 0):

Given $Nx=Ny$.
Since $N$ is a subgroup of $G$, $1\in N$.
Therefore, $x=1x\in Nx=Ny$.
This means that $x=ny$ for some $n\in N$.
Multiplying both sides by $y^{-1}$ we get $$xy^{-1}=n\in N$$